# I'm adding an action to a plugin but I get a 404 error at the URL where I expect to find the view

Tags: php, cakephp

My Email Forms plugin works properly, and I'm trying to add an Email Forms Submission action for viewing submitted email forms from the admin.

The directory tree looks like this, the files I've added are starred.

```
app/plugins/email_forms
    controllers
        email_forms_controller.php
        **email_form_submissions_controller.php**
    models
        email_form.php
        **email_form_submission.php**
    views
        email_forms
            admin_view.ctp
        email_forms_submissions
            **admin_view.ctp**
            **admin_index.ctp**
```

And in the database I have a table called email_form_submissions.
So when I go to http://www.example.com/admin/email-forms/email_form_submissions/index, I expect to see a blank view of admin_index.ctp. Instead I get a 404.

The controller and model file don't have any code in them, just boilerplate "class EmailFormSubmissionsController extends AppController {}"

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you reading through the CakePHP cookbook, as it seems that you're confused on some pretty fundamental stuff:  http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/

Second of all, it would help if you put your version number of Cake.  From your naming scheme, I'm guessing you're using Cake 1.X, so I'm going to write my answer that way.

Third of all, it's not entirely clear from your question what email form submissions actually is.  Is it an action belonging to email_forms_controller.php?  Is it a controller?  In my answer, I'm going to assume that it's actually a controller, since your code and file structure seem to indicate this.

**Adding a new page**

Basic CakePHP URL's are of the following format, unless you change them from the default behavior, by altering your routes file.  The arguments are optional.

```
http://domain.com/prefix/controller/action[/arg1/arg2/etc...]
```

To create a corresponding page, you first need to add it to the controller:

```
class Controller extends AppController
{
      function prefix_action($arg1, $arg2, etc...) {}
}
```

Then you create a view file and put in the appropriate location in your views folder:

```
views
     controller
            prefix_action.ctp
```

In your case, you already have a view file in the appropriate spot.  But you still need to add to the controller:

```
class EmailFormSubmissionsController extends AppController 
{
     function admin_index() {}
}
```

Then, you should find the page at (note that the action is "index", the last "index" in the URL is actually optional, so I left it off):

```
http://www.example.com/admin/email_form_submissions
```

Comment: I think I may have left out some information - in our applications, I never touch the files in app/views. All that is canon code and doesn't change much. We do all our development through plugins, so I'm working from the Email Forms plugin. That plugin allows our clients to create pages that contain email forms. When someone uses the form, an email is sent to the site owner, but we want to save those emails in our admin backend as well. So that's what this function is for, finding and displaying saved email form submissions. I don't quite understand your answer - I DO have a controller.

Comment: Yes, you do have a controller, but you need to add an action to your controller, or it will not work.  My answer should still pretty much work for a Plugin, except that it changes the URL you should navigate to -- http://www.example.com/admin/email_forms/email_form_submissions, if I remember the naming conventions correctly.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, I do have controller actions in there:

     function admin_view () {
  //select email form submission by id and set it to the view
  
 } 

 function admin_index() {
  // select all email form submissions grouped by form name and set to the view
 }

I think there must be something else though, cause it's still a 404.

Comment: In that case, I'm not entirely sure the url you posted is correct for that location -- http://www.example.com/admin/email_forms/email_form_submissions/index (underscore instead of hyphen)?

Comment: No dice. admin/email_forms/email_form_submissions/view doesn't work either.